# How do I post some introductory paragraphs on the main page of my blogdown site?

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown, toml

My initial `menu` for my blogdown site is taken directly from the [blogdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/themes.html#the-default-theme).

```
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Home"
    url = "/"
    weight = 1
[[menu.main]]
    name = "About"
    url = "/about/"
    weight = 2
[[menu.main]]
    name = "GitHub"
    url = "https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown"
    weight = 3
[[menu.main]]
    name = "CV"
    url = "/vitae/"
    weight = 4
[[menu.main]]
    name = "Twitter"
    url = "https://twitter.com/rstudio"
    weight = 5
```

The index of my site automatically populates with any posts I add via `Addins > New Post`. If I alter my `index.Rmd` file in my main project directory (shown below) no changes occur on my front landing *'homepage'*.

```
├── archetypes/
├── content/
├── data/
├── layouts/
├── public/
├── ...
├── config.toml
├── index.Rmd
└── my-website.Rproj
```

My `index.Rmd` file looks like this, although my website won't publish my intended paragraph on my main 'homepage'.

```
---
site: blogdown:::blogdown_site
---

# Intended first paragraph
Hi. Thank you for visiting my website... more words... etc
```

To further complicate matters, there is no `_index.md` file in my `content/` directory. Could this be the issue? I'd like to post some introductory paragraphs before all my posts appear on the main page (homepage) of my blogdown website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to create `_index.md` under `content/`. Then the content of `_index.md` will be displayed on your homepage.

There was a minor issue with the `hugo-lithium` theme, which [I just fixed on Github](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-lithium/commit/23d456ea0acde1299d9b839352339d59fd342d5a). In the old version, if `_index.md` is not empty, the list of posts will not be displayed. Now both the content and the list of posts will be displayed. If that is not what you want, you can certainly revert my change in `layouts/_default/list.html`.

Comment: If I ever want to revert changes (I don't right now)... well... my `layouts/` directory is empty. Do I create a `_default/` directory inside of `layouts/`? Then create a file `list.html` inside the `_default` directory? And what do I put in the body of my `list.html` file?

Comment: Your files under `layouts/` will override those under the theme dir with the same names, so you just copy that `list.html` to your `layouts/_default/` and make changes there.

Comment: @JasonHunter - you might want to think about [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Aha! I just realized there's a `/layouts/` directory and also a separate `/themes/hugo-lithium/layouts/` directory. Now it's starting to make sense. And I'll populate my `list.html` with the body from your *pre-Github-fix* `list.html` file, should I want the old behavior.